# JSで抽出データを目的のシートの各カラムにいれるスクリプト作成したがうまくいかない

Tags: google-apps-script

以下GASを記載します。
表題の通りですが、最後の行でlnngthがおかしいといわれます。
何故でしょうか。

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("元");
var record_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("レポート");

function writeData() {

  var val = record_sheet.getRange(8,3).getValue(); //使い回す
  var record_data = data_sheet.getRange("A:l").getValues();
  var set_array = [];
  var name_array = [];

  //1行目は列名なので飛ばす
  for (var i = 1; i <= record_data.length; i++) {
    if (record_data[i][0] == "") {
      break;
    //セルC8と同じ値の時
    } else if (record_data[i][0] == val) {
      set_array.push(record_data[i]);  
      name_array.push(record_data[i][1]);
    }
  }

  //[[1行目の値],[２行目の値],..]
  var record_name_row = record_sheet.getRange("C:C").getValues().slice(11);
  record_name_row = record_name_row.join(",").split(",");
  var new_set_array = [[], []];
  var copy_array;

  for (var i = 0; i <= record_name_row.length - 1; i++) {
    if (record_name_row[i] == "") {
      break;
    } else {
      copy_array = [];
      new_set_array[0].push(set_array[name_array.indexOf(record_name_row[i])].slice(3,5));
      val = set_array[name_array.indexOf(record_name_row[i])].slice(5,9);
      val = set_array[name_array.indexOf(record_name_row[i])].slice(9,10);
      //1000%などおかしな値になるので文字列に直す
      val = val.forEach(function(num) {
        copy_array.push(num.toString());
      });
      new_set_array[1].push(copy_array);
    }
  }

  record_sheet.getRange(12,6,new_set_array[0].length,2).setValues(new_set_array[0]);
  record_sheet.getRange(12,14,new_set_array[1].length,4).setValues(new_set_array[1]);
  record_sheet.getRange(12,10,new_set_array[2].length,1).setValues(new_set_array[2]);

}
```

Comment: `var new_set_array = [[], []];` と宣言していますので、アクセス可能なのは`new_set_array[0]` と `new_set_array[1]` だけです。

Comment: なるほど、有難うございます。